# Tablesorter zebra widget breaks sortability

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have put this code together to create a table, but when I include the zebra widget - I can only sort the columns to *descend*. I cannot make the ascend or bring them back to normal, however the zebra widget works :D

Is there anything wrong with my code here? Thanks :)

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

         $("#myTable").tablesorter({  

         $("table").tablesorter({ 
         widgets: ['zebra','repeatHeaders'] 
         }); 
});
```

Edit: I also tried changing 'table' to '#myTable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you open it twice?

It should be

```
$(function() {      
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know why it never occurred to me. Thanks Marco :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the widget in as described [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-widgets.html) and then call it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        // Sort Specific Table //
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();

        // Sort Specific Table and Add Zebra to it only //
        $('#myTable').tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra','repeatHeaders']});

        // Add Zebra Plugin to All Tables //    
        $("table").tablesorter({ 
            widgets: ['zebra','repeatHeaders'] 
        });
    } 
);
```